# Laravel: Rename a file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have files saved in the next route:
`/resources/views/projects/nameproject.blade.php`

I have a form where I put the new name of the project and I want to make a rename of the file created with the name of project, for example:

I have a project called lluistestbefore, her route it's this:
`/resources/views/projects/lluistestbefore.blade.php`

When I submit the Form I give a new value called: lluistestafter, the route should be:

`/resources/views/projects/lluistestafter.blade.php`

The controller function looks like:

```
public function updateProject(Request $request, $id) //Update the project info 
        { 
           $project = Project::find($id); //Find which project is

                $oldSlug = $project->slug; //save the old value into the variable

                $project->order = $request->input('order'); //it's not important
                $project->public = $request->input('public'); //it's not important

                if (strcmp($oldSlug, $request->input('slug')) !== 0) { //If slug change enter to the if

                Storage::disk('projects')->move($project->slug, $request->input('slug')); //it's not important

                $project->slug = $request->input('slug'); //get the value of the new slug

                $project->pathheader = $request->input('slug').'/header.jpg'; //it's not important

                $project->pathhome = $request->input('slug').'/home.jpg';  //it's not important

                File::move('/resources/views/projects/'.$oldSlug.'.blade.php','/resources/views/projects/'.$project->slug.'.blade.php'); //Function which is not working correctly and give me the error.
            }
        }
```

The error is this: 
`rename(/resources/views/projects/lluistestantes.blade.php,/resources/views/projects/lluistestdespues.blade.php): No such file or directory`

Comment: If you start the path with a `/`, your operating system will usually think you mean from the root of your partition. Use absolute paths or set the path relative to your working directory.

Comment: Can you answer with the correct syntax? I try it without / at the beginning, and also tried with public_path().

Comment: It depends on your setup, but e.g. `app_path('resources/views/projects/lluistestantes.blade.php')` or similar.

Comment: app_path? i never see it before

Comment: That doesn't mean it doesn't exist. Actually, better yet, use resource_path(): https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-resource-path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
File::move(resource_path('views/projects/'.$oldSlug.'.blade.php'),resource_path('views/projects/'.$project->slug.'.blade.php'));
```

Comment: I can't seem to make the `Storage::move` happen, but this worked for me perfectly. thanks! `[+1]`